# Telerik, Infragistics, XCeed,

Tags: wpf, mvvm, grid, telerik, xceed

I'm looking for a vendor for a grid control for WPF that works nicely together with MVVM; and that allows grouping by dragging the columns. I've been looking around and at first sight it seems that my choice at the moment would be Telerik. 
If there are people that have experience with one or more vendors, I would like to hear your opinion.
Thanks!
L

Comment: Just use `ObjectListView`.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xceed DataGrid for WPF does support MVVM. You can refer to their product page for more information [here](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Intro.html) and you can also refer to their extensive and online documentation [here](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfDataGrid/).

After installation, you are also given many sample applications that are installed on your machine. You can find them here:

C:\Xceed Samples\Xceed DataGrid for WPF Professional Edition vX.X

Answer (score 2):

did you try the dataGrid included in WPF .net 4.0?
as MS finally added one, you could first try to use it and see if it suits your needs.

except of course if you are limited (having to use .net prior to v4.0 for instance...)

see there for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: I had a look at the built in datagrid, but can you do grouping by dragging the columns instead of doing it programatically?

Comment: not that I know of :/ you'd probably have to get your hands dirty on this one. I think you should edit your question and add the requirements the datagrid you're looking for has to fulfill, this will help narrow the criteria